# link/bind a directory into a NFS exported folder

Tags: nfs

Have a Linux PC and an ARM-board. Want to boot the ARM-board into a rootfs hosted on the PC (cross/remote)

I export a rootfs in my home, so /etc/exports looks like:

```
/home/user/rootfs 172.20.20.0/24(anonuid=0,anongid=0,async,rw,no_subtree_check)
```

Now I want that a certain folder (lets assume /home/user/example/opt) is linked to
/home/user/rootfs/opt. That works fine via a mount bind. So at PC I can navigate through directories and see that files in /home/user/rootfs/opt 
BUT:
The device that boots into that NFS doesn't see this /opt folder (or the content in it).

Do I have a chance to solve that? Maybe I need a different approach or have to add a line in /etc/exports fo my PC?

Comment: what? are you attempting to file share between a windows pc and your ubuntu? what's the context?

Comment: This is for cross/remote development. On PC (Linux PX) is a rootfs hosted for arm board (as beagleboard ...). The rootfs is created by tool (yocto) but in /opt/ I want to have some own stuff (which is not part of yocto). I could copy that part each time a new rootfs is installed but link it would be more convenient.

Comment: I see, and the arm machine boots something that cannot be changed and cannot read ext4 but can read nfs? and fat32 is out because it doesn't support soft links?

Comment: No, NFS works fine. arm machine boots into rootfs. But it can't see the content of /opt, as it not physically in the root folder but mounted on the host-pc into it. So on host-PC it is fine, the opt folder is properly mounted into the (arm-) rootfs at /home/user/rootfs. The arm device see this as it's /, but it can't see the /opt - folder content

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: Other attempt: In your Linux PC you might have 2 partitions, / and /home. At you PC /home is mounted into /, so if you browse through directories you don't know about multiple partition.  And now imagine you have exported your / to another device that want's to boot into this /. It will not see /home.  This is simular to what I want to have in my exported rootfs. (BTW, why does line break doesn't work here?)

Comment: comments are mostly meant for one liners. so enter sends the message but if you add shift it works (just like on any other app for which enter sends). but if you mean why are line breaks removed in the end, it's to save space in the comments.